# gulp - how to run something in pipe and let next pipe to wait?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Let say I have a `gulp` task, something like:

```
gulp.src('bla-bla')
  .pipe(smth())
  .pipe(epic()) // I want to run gulp task here and wait for its end
  .pipe(livereload());
```

I want to run a gulp task after `smth()` finished and I want to ensure that `livereload()` started exactly after inserted gulp task finished. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

For now, your best bet is likely `run-sequence`: https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence

Gulp is supposedly integrating this functionality directly in 4.0, but for now you can use runSequence to accomplish the same.

In the context of your question:

```
gulp.task('one', function() {
  return gulp.src('bla-bla')
    .pipe(smth())
    .pipe(epic())
})

gulp.task('two', function() {
  return livereload.reload()
})

gulp.task('runboth', function() {
  runSequence('one', 'two')
});
```

You may have to throw in a callback depending on what `.reload()` returns.  See https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence#usage

Comment: Could you show me how to do it in the context of my question?